# How to exclude the last element in an unordered list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I have an unordered list (`ul`) and a few list's elements (`li`).
I'd like to bind all the `li`'s except the last one.

Example:

```
$('ul li').on('click', someFunction);

$('ul li:last-child').off('click');
```

Using jQuery, is there a way to do it in one line of code?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with the selector `:not` :

```
$('#elementName li:not(:last-child)').on('click', someFunction);
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 7 seconds :O

Comment: Solved my question! Thanks for your quick replay!

Answer (score 2):

This selector should work:

```
$('#elementName li:not(:last-child)').on('click', someFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('#elementName li:not(:last-child)').on('click', someFunction);
```